# how to apply gsub on string elements within an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

for example, I have an array which is structured as follow:

```
my_array = [["..\\..\\..\\Source\\file1.c"], ["..\\..\\..\\Source\\file2.c"]]
```

This array is produced by this code:

```
File.open(file_name) do |f|
    f.each_line {|line|
      if line =~ /<ClCompile Include="..\\/
        my_array << line.scan(/".*.c"/)
      end
    }
  end
```

Later in the code I'm working on the array:

```
my_array .each {|n| f.puts n.gsub(/\\/,"//")}
```

As you can see, would like to replace all the backslashes with forward slashes on the elements within the array. The elements presents paths to source files. On the end I will output these paths within an other file.

I get this error:

```
undefined method `gsub' for [["..\\..\\..\\Source\\file1.c"], ["..\\..\\..\\Source\\file2.c"]]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Any idea?

Comment: where does the "f" come from?

Comment: Use `my_array.flatten.each` instead (you have a multi-dimensional Array, an Array of Arrays, and `flatten` will make it a one-dimensional Array)

Comment: @bosskovic: Have improved the question (explained more detailed) so that you can see where "f" comes from

Comment: please try flattening the array as I suggested in my updated answer, and see if that works for you.

Comment: @bosskovic: yes it worked! ... cool method :)

Comment: You've opened the file to read, so you can't `puts` to it. You need to first close the file and then reopen to write, or open a new file to write.  Also, the space in `my_array .` just won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of arrays, so if you want to keep it like that, you would need to have 2 loops.

Otherwise, if you change your variable to this: `my_array = ["..\\..\\..\\Source\\file1.c", "..\\..\\..\\Source\\file2.c"]` your code should work.

---

UPDATE

if you can not control `my_array`, and it is always an array of one item arrays, perhaps this is cleanest:

```
my_array.flatten.each {|n| puts n.gsub(/\\/,"//")}
```

What it does is transforms two-dimensional array in one-dimensional.

Comment: Have tested it and it works! Didn't know about the "flatten" method .... cool , thx! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
my_array.flatten.each { |n| f.puts n.tr('\\', '/') }
```

Comment: I like your use of [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr), but would suggest `my_array.each { |n| f.puts n.first.tr('\\', '/') }` to avoid the creation of an unnecessary temporary array. (This is after a file with handle `f` is opened for writing.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you are calling gsub on an array, not the string within it. You want:

```
my_array.each {|n| puts n[0].gsub(/\\/,"//")}
```

Comment: This only does the `gsub` on the first of the two nested arrays. It'd be better to use `flatten` or also iterate over the nested arrays. IMO it doesn't make much sense to hardcodedly only get the first nested array.

Comment: @Mischa, this seems a rather specific requirement. I don't know if the time required to write and test a method that will permit arbitrary levels of nesting is justified when the method's grater potential may never be realized. It's a balancing act.